# Android view ScrollView LinearLayout on top

Tags: android

I want to get huge view, which I have to scroll. I want to get a one part of of view always on a phone screen in my code is a  `LinearLayout` I want to display always on screen. Into my `LinearLayout` I put  `layout_alignParentTop` but when I scroll it disappears.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="3.5">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Jan Nowak"
                            android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal_size"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_user_mail"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_name"
                            android:text="jan.nowak@gmail.com"
                            android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal_size" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: U want a specific view to always show on top and doesnt move whereas all the other views should be scrollable? which view u want to keep static???

Comment: @PrajwalW LinearLayout but I a LinearLayout wpould be under map,

Comment: You havent mentioned anyhting about it. What do you actually want state in a single sentence...Also in your xml pasted, there is no map view.

Comment: simple suggestion: you should avoid such complex nesting in the layouts. Use `ConstraintLayout` instead

Answer (score 0):

**Made few changes:**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3.5">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="Jan Nowak"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_name"
                android:id="@+id/tv_user_mail"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:text="jan.nowak@gmail.com"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**If you want to keep a view static and other scrollable and keep that view outside of your scrollview....**